# How to allow user key in first character alphabet/numeric and the rest must numeric?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex, numeric

Hi i have a field that allows only alphabet or numeric in First character, and the rest only allow numeric only, and no allow symbols/space etc.

how to make the jquery/code?

Comment: Create a javascript file, and reference the file so that it interacts with your HTML and add the code there.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple regex:

```
/^[a-z0-9]\d*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating Jack answer little bit and convert to working snippet.

```js
$('#yourid').on("keyup", function() {
  let val = $(this).val();
  let reg = /^[a-z0-9]\d*$/
  let newval = val.replace(reg, '');
  if (!val.match(reg)) {
    $(this).val(''); // clear the field if pattern don't match. 
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='yourid' />
```

How above regex work.

> ^ asserts position at start of the string
>
> Match a single character present in the list below [a-z0-9]
>
> a-z a single character in the range between a  and z (case sensitive)
>
> 0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9 (case sensitive)
>
> \d* matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
> * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
>
> $ asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line
> terminator right at the end of the string (if any)